# What is the error in this SQL code it shows error ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression, with-statement

Pls help me with this code what wrong with it

```sql
WITH CTE_contest as
(
SELECT c.contest_id,c.hacker_id,c.name,s.total_submissions
,s.total_accepted_submissions,v.total_views,v.total_unique_views,ch.challenge_id
FROM
    contests c
    join colleges cg on c.contest_id = cg.contest_id
    join challenges ch on cg.college_id = ch.college_id
    join view_stats v on ch.challenge_id = v.challenge_id
    join submission_stats s on ch.challenge_id = s.challenge_id
group by c.contest_id,c.hacker_id,ch.challenge_id
)
select contest_id,hacker_id,name,sum(total_submissions) as tl_sub
,sum(total_accepted_submissions) as tl_asub,sum(total_views) as tl_v
,sum(total_unique_views) as tl_uv
from CTE_contest
group by contest_id,hacker_id,name
having tl_sub and tl_asub and tl_v and tl_uv != 0
order by contest_id;
```

please explain why is not working

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you should remove `group by` clause from the CTE (there are no aggregates there so - maybe you wanted to use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead?) and modify `having` clause. Something like this:

```
WITH cte_contest AS (
    SELECT
        c.contest_id,
        c.hacker_id,
        c.name,
        s.total_submissions,
        s.total_accepted_submissions,
        v.total_views,
        v.total_unique_views,
        ch.challenge_id
    FROM
             contests c
        JOIN colleges         cg ON c.contest_id = cg.contest_id
        JOIN challenges       ch ON cg.college_id = ch.college_id
        JOIN view_stats       v ON ch.challenge_id = v.challenge_id
        JOIN submission_stats s ON ch.challenge_id = s.challenge_id
   )
SELECT
    contest_id,
    hacker_id,
    name,
    SUM(total_submissions)          AS tl_sub,
    SUM(total_accepted_submissions) AS tl_asub,
    SUM(total_views)                AS tl_v,
    SUM(total_unique_views)         AS tl_uv
FROM
    cte_contest
GROUP BY
    contest_id,
    hacker_id,
    name
having SUM(total_submissions) != 0 
   and SUM(total_accepted_submissions) != 0
   and SUM(total_views) != 0
   AND SUM(total_unique_views) != 0
order by contest_id;
```